# Scala/Play 2 - Can't get sample specs2 test to run

Tags: scala, playframework, dependencies, playframework-2.0, specs2

I'm using the Play Framework v2.04 with Scala on OS X (installed via Homebrew). Everything works as expected, however I can't seem to get the basic [*Hello World* sample specs2 test from the Play website's documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/ScalaTest) to run. This is the code within my `/app/test/example.scala` file:

```scala
import org.specs2.mutable._

import play.api.test._
import play.api.test.Helpers._

class HelloWorldSpec extends Specification {

  "The 'Hello world' string" should {
    "contain 11 characters" in {
      "Hello world" must have size(11)
    }
    "start with 'Hello'" in {
      "Hello world" must startWith("Hello")
    }
    "end with 'world'" in {
      "Hello world" must endWith("world")
    }
  }
}
```

However when I run `play test`, I get the following error:

```sh
[error] /app/test/example.scala:3: object test is not a member of package play.api
```

AFAIK, the test object ***should*** be a member of the play.api package ([according to the API reference documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0.4/scala/index.html#play.api.test.package)).

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Try moving the class under the `test` folder, and renaming it `Example.scala`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create `test` directory under the project root directory and move the `example.scala` from `app/test` to `test`.

Answer (score 0):

In IntelliJ IDEA "Mark Directory as" > "Test Sources root".
With the right click in the project window.

IDEA may be mislead by non-standard project layout.
Usually test libraries are of dependency type "test" and will not compile when not recognized as "test" code.